# Validating an 11-digit string input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I'm trying to make sure the input in a particular field is just an 11 digit number, however my if condition does not seem to be working:

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function check() {
        var x = document.forms["myform"]["mobile"].value;
        if (!/^\d{11}$/.test(x)) {
            myform.action="gender.html";
        else { 
            myform.action="mobilerror.html"
        }
    }
</script>
```

And the HTML is:

```
<form id="myform"  onsubmit="check();" >
    <input class="input" type="text" name="mobile" required="required"
   oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Number is empty')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
</form>
```

Please help!

Comment: define "not working"

Comment: According to your code, `mobilerror.html` is called when the 'mobile' field _does_ content a 11-digit number. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: @DylanMeeus whatever I enter in the mobile field, no action is taken, neither gender.html nor mobilerror.html are loaded

Comment: @Arnauld, I can switch up which pages to call, it's just that no matter what the input is no new page is loaded and the same current page is just reloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression is working just fine. I think the error lies in the "if" condition. Try changing

```
if (!/^\d{11}$/.test(x)) {
 myform.action="gender.html";
else { 
 myform.action="mobilerror.html"
}
```

to this

```
if (/^\d{11}$/.test(x)) {
 myform.action="gender.html";
else { 
 myform.action="mobilerror.html"
}
```

As you can see I just took off the negation in the expression.

Note: Assuming that the "mobilerror.html" is shown when the user didn't type the 11 digit as expected.

Comment: You're a genius, and I feel stupid :D Thanks! This worked just fine!

Answer (score 1):

You can try maxlength and type attribute of input field:

```
 <input class="input" type="text" name="mobile" maxlength="11" type="number" required="required"/>
```

If it satisfy your case then you don't need to call javascript function.

Comment: And if it's a number you could change the input to `type="number"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 function check() {
  var x = document.forms["myform"]["mobile"].value;
  var pattern = new RegExp("^1?([1-9])(\\d{10})");
  if (pattern.test(x)) {
     myform.action="gender.html";
  } else {
    myform.action="mobilerror.html"
  }
}
```

`^1?([1-9])` checks if the first number is not zero, so that the input value is numerically a 11-digit number. If you don't want it you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

This help you :

use type 'number':

```
<input type="number" id="number" class="input">
```

and test number digits is 11 or not with :

```
var patt = /.{11}/;
```

Example :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myform"  onsubmit="check()" >
           <input id="number" class="input" type="number">
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
       </form>
        <script>
              var patt = /.{11}/;
            function check(){
                var num = document.getElementById("number").value;
                var frm = document.getElementById("myform");
                if(patt.test(num))
                    frm.action ="mobilerror.html"
                else
                    frm.action = "gender.html";

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Sophia111 , check my answer.